# How can I overwrite a UITableViewCell after its creation with a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not quite understanding tableview's behavior as a whole:

I have a tableview with one dynamic cell (reuseIdentifier: cell) which I defined in storyboard. In addition to that I have two custom tableviewcells created with two nib files. 
The cell is created like this of course:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The problem is that this cell is created for every indexPath there is. How can I overwrite the created cell at a certain indexPath with a customized tableviewcell? Even if I have an if-condition like the following where it's explicitly coded to return the customizedCell the normal cell is returned... How's that even possible?

```
if (indexPath.row == 4) {
    return customizedCell;
}
```

Comment: You could add those custom cells with their own identifier as prototype to your tableview in your storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you have the `reuseIdentifier` for - your custom cells should have their own `reuseIdentifiers`, and you have to dequeue the cells for those `reuseIdentifiers` for the rows you want to have the custom cells in.

Comment: Perfect! This answer got me to see that I create the UITableViewCell *cell with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:**forIndexPath:**. If I leave out the **forIndexPath:** it works perfectly fine, which makes, in retrospective, perfect sense! Thanks!